# Unable to pause submit handler for showing transition page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have page it has two div's. On submitting form it must hide one div and show another.
I use jQuery for validating method for validating that form.
Second div that I'm showing is a transition div it must stay for 5 seconds. But I cannot able to pause submit Handler. It sends request to server when submit Handler executed. Please help.

```
submitHandler : function (form) {
    div1.hide();
    div2.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do it's something like this:

```
submitHandler : function (form) {
    $("#divId1").show();
    $("#divId1").delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');

}
```

where "divId1" its a div like this:

```
<div id="divId1">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: div2 is transition page(it says you are redirecting) it has to shown to user for some time(say 5 sec). But request post to server without waiting for delay.